# Understanding Obfuscated Song Lyrics in 夢うつつ - Dream

Tags: verbs, adverbs, song-lyrics, transcription

I have previously asked a question regarding what is being said in this song, but it did not follow guidelines since I was not asking anything specific. However, in consulting with my teacher on the song, I have limited the unknown lyrics in [夢うつつ - Dream](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=40DYuMqyuFA) to just two areas. My question is basically just asking you in this community if you may know what would be said here given the context. The song in general is about escaping into a dream to deal with the troubles of living.

The first line my teacher could not figure out starts at 2:03 and the second is the next line after; this follows some English lyrics about the peace one gets in their dreams:

> ゆらりと　揺らいだところ　さえ　**やそうだきにかわる**

> **あしょう**　変わりない　日々に　臆すること　何でも　やってみなちゃ　分からないんだ

These are the only two circumstances throughout the song that are still vague to my teacher and I. The first in bold is likely some conjugation, while the second is likely an adverb of sorts. Do any of you know what any of these could mean? I am running out of options.

Comment: Are you sure about the part after あしょう (or whatever the first word is)? I heard X 恥ずかしい instead of X 変わりない日々に.

Comment: You are right; I mis-transcribed the lyrics on the question.... :,(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it kinda sounds as

> ゆらりと　揺らいだところ<sup>1</sup>　さえ　**やすらぎに　かわる　ばしょ**

ところ<sup>1</sup> could be こころ.

As commented, then follows '恥ずかしい..'.

Comment: Thank you very much; this makes much more sense. I will look at what I have so far to ensure everything makes sense in my transcription.